# How to add Text next to the Image in Page Header

Tags: html, css

I am newbie to Web designing. I am trying to create a Page header. Basically my idea is like this:

[HTML Layout wire frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRXfw.png)

Thanking in Advance:)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular. We expect to see what you've already tried by providing code in your question, preferably in a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to achieve this. YOu can add bootstrap to your html script like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then you can have something like this for your page header:

```
    <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Much longer nav link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

Please also read up on the bootstrap docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)